# Agregar caracteres especiales en PHP @#%&-+()/*"':;!?~|{}[]_

Tags: php, caracteres

Mi consulta es la siguiente, quiero agregar caracteres especiales en un campo especifico , en este caso es donde dice cordon, el codigo es en  `PHP`, pero no encuentro como modificar el codigo para que me acepte los caracteres en la base de datos lo tengo como una entrada text. 
Mi código es este:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-()9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevaDescripcion"])
```

esta es la foto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Seria excelente que des un poco mas de contexto a tu pregunta, en el titulo expresas que quieres ***permitir*** carateres especiales y en el cuerpo de la pregunta lo cambias a: ***agregar*** caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar un :

```
if (preg_match('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])\S{30}$', $_POST["nuevaDescripcion"]))
{
    return true; //Ejemplo
}
```

Donde `S{30}` Es la cantidad de caracteres a permitir.
Espero te sirva de ayuda, Saludos. 
***Pd: Te dejo una imagen de validación de la expresión.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]